# Is it possible to log the custom errors into log file instead of csv file in Talend

Tags: etl, talend

I want to log the errors in Log file(.log) instead of csv file because even I have to use .csv file i will have to use multiple files each time we log the errors. Creating multiple CSV file is difficult for maintenance. How can i solve this problem. Is the better way to put the errors into Log files.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few details missing such as how you are generating these logs and what is the difference in your mind between a .log file and a .csv file.

Here are my suggestions based on what I understand from your question:

You can use any extension you want in your tFileOutputDelimited, including .log.

If you want to save all the logs in one file, just click the "append" checkbox in the tFileOutputDelimited. Beware that this might make your file quite large.

Comment: I am generating the log files using tOutputExcel. Using this i am not able to write it into same file in multiple place say while inserting to DB at success scenario i want to log all the records and Failure scenario i want to log into same file. I tried doing this but was trowing error. I even tried giving the different Sheet name which is also not possible.

Comment: Using tFileOutputDelimited i am able to write into same .csv or .log file. But if i try with .xlsx file it is creating the file but i am not able to open the file. Can you please suggest me how to work this out with excel files.

Comment: I'm not sure why you were getting an error. The `tOutputExcel` component also has an `append` option. Maybe because the file did not exist at first? You might need to create an empty file before you try to append anything onto it. In that case you can use a `tFixedFlow --> tOutputExcel` (with the `append` option unchecked), making the data in the `tFixedFlow` blank or null.